# Allow quantity selection even when price is zero

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code string that does the following...

Condition: only if product category is 'stone' then

1. adds "per ft squared" after the price
2. if the price is left empty, instead of it saying $0 it says "call for price"

Goal: when the product doesnt have a price or is zero, I want the quantity selector to remain visible on the product page.

```html
// Add's feet squared to pricing only if prododuct category is 'stone'

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message' );
 
function custom_price_message($price) {
 
if ( !has_term( 'stone', 'product_cat' ) ) {
   return $price;
    
} elseif (!empty($price)){
   $vat = ' per ft<sup>2</sup>';
   return $price . $vat;
    
 }else{
   return 'Call for Price';
 }
```

Comment: yes something like if price is zero... return do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' );

Answer (score 0):

Found it! This makes no purchasable product purchasable

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'wpa_109409_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );

function wpa_109409_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ){
    if( $product->get_price() >= 0 )
        $purchasable = true;
    return $purchasable;
}
```